# Build SSIS project inside Docker Windows build container

Tags: docker, ssis, azure-devops, dockerfile

I have a Windows container which has VS 2017 build tools with .NET core 2.2 and able to build .NET core projects well. Now, how can I get SSIS project which is in same .NET core solution gets build in same container? Are there any work-arounds?

```
RUN C:\TEMP\Install.cmd C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
--channelUri C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman `
--installChannelUri C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman `
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools `
--add Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.4.6.2.DeveloperTools `
--add Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.TargetingPacks.Common `
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.BuildTools `
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools `    
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools `
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools `
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.UniversalBuildTools `
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools `
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.DataBuildTools
```

Tried with

```
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.SQL/SSIS
```

but no help.

Is it possible to build with SSIS?

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the blog which provided in Leo's answer could help you solve the puzzle? Feel free to leave comment there if you still facing any issue or puzzle:-)

Comment: New to Docker for Desktop - can you add a path to a Windows source where the latest SQL 2019 SQL Server Integration Services Projects link has be used to download the installer for SSIS and SSDT (Microsoft.DataTools.Integration.Services.exe)?  Possibly with PowerShell?  Can Bash download the executable? (Access the ManageExtensions via VS2019 and upload the exe?)

Answer (score 3):

> Build SSIS project inside docker windows build container

I am afraid build SSIS project inside docker windows build container is not supported at this moment.

We could to know there is user voice from Microsoft side:

[Add SSIS to the SQL Server Docker Image](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35208061-add-ssis-to-the-sql-server-docker-image)

And the issue about to [support SSIS](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/213) is still open as well.

You could  vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Besides, tere is a very [good blog](https://andyleonard.blog/2018/12/ssis-docker-and-windows-containers-part-0-getting-started/) written by a pioneer, you can refer it for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Azure now supports SSIS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-lift-shift-ssis-packages-overview?view=sql-server-ver15.  Does this help?